# How do you generate a preview of html code in other window fetched from a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which generates a html code in a text box.

When code generation happens parallel I am inserting the same code in a table.

All this is in between asp controllers.

Under that text box I have button called preview.

All I need is when I click on the button it should fetch the code and preview it like html file in other window.

If saving that code in not a good idea than help to give another alternate.

All I need is preview of that code in html format in other window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with JavaScript. Open a new window and write the contents of your text box on the new window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function preview()
{
var hwnd=window.open('','preview','[window attributes such as height width etc.]');
hwnd.document.write(document.getElementById('<id of your textbox>').value);
hwnd.document.close();
}
</script>
```

on you preview button tag add `onclick=preview()`

Comment: I found a solution.... Its better to convert all your code into simple html rather by using asp controls and it works